# PHP - Submit form using Get method.

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using Get method to add data that has been entered by user to the event table in database

as you can see I'm using the get method to see if the user has posted and then run the code 
but the if statement does not run and I can't find out where is the problem.

Any help would be useful

Thank you very much

```
if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
    $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];
    $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO book (title, detail, eventdat, dateadded) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$detail}', '{$eventdate}',now())";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlinsert, $connect);
    if($result)
    {
        echo"date has been added";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ops there was problem ";
    }
}
```

this is the full Code 
event.php

```
<?php 
    include_once('db_connection.php');
$sqlinsert="";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function goLastMonth(month, year)
{
    if(month==1)
    {
        --year
        month= 13;
    }
    --month
    var monthstring=""+month+"";
    var monthlength=  monthstring.length;
    if(monthlength<= 1)
    {
        monthstring="0"+monthstring;
    }
    document.location.href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> ?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
}
function goNextMonth(month , year)
{
    if(month==12)
    {
        ++year
        month= 0;
    }
    ++month
    var monthstring=""+month+"";
    var monthlength=  monthstring.length;
    if(monthlength<= 1)
    {
        monthstring="0"+monthstring;
    }
    document.location.href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> ?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['day']))
{
    $day=$_GET['day'];
}
else 
{
    $day=date('j');
}
if(isset($_GET['month']))
{
    $month=$_GET['month'];
}
else 
{
    $month=date("n");
}
if(isset($_GET['year']))
{
    $year=$_GET['year'];
}
else 
{
    $year=date("Y");
}
$t=date('H:i');
//$day=date('j');
//$month=date("n");
//$year=date("Y");
$time=$day.",".$month.",".$year;
$currenttimestamp= strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
$monthname=date("F",$currenttimestamp );
$numdays= date("t",$currenttimestamp);

if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
    $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];
    $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO book (title, detail, eventdat, dateadded) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$detail}', '{$eventdate}',now())";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlinsert, $connect);
    if($result)
    {
        echo"date has been added";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ops there was problem ";
    }
}

?>
<?php echo $sqlinsert;?>
<table border="2">
<tr>
<td colspan="5">Month And Year <?php echo $monthname;?></td>
<td ><input style="width:55px" type="button" value="<<" name="previousbutton" onclick="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month. ",".$year;?>)"> </td>
<td> <input style="width:55px"  type="button" value=">>" name="nextbutton" onclick="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month. ",".$year;?>)">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50">Sun</td>
<td width="50">Mon</td>
<td width="50">Tue</td>
<td width="50">Wed</td>
<td width="50">Thu</td>
<td width="50">Fri</td>
<td width="50">Sat</td>
</tr>


<?php 
$counter="";
echo "<tr >";
for ($i=1;$i< $numdays+1; $i++, $counter++)
{
    $timeStamp=strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
    if($i==1)
    {
        $firstDay=date("w", $timeStamp);
        for($j=0;$j<$firstDay; $j++, $counter++)
    //blank space
        {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
    if($counter %7==0)
    {
    echo "</tr><tr>";   

    }
    $monthstring=$month;
    $monthlength= strlen ($monthstring);
    //
    $daystring=$i;
    $daylength= strlen($daystring);
    if($monthlength<=1)
    {
        $monthstring="0".$monthstring;
    }
    if($daylength<=1)
    {
    $daystring="0".$daystring;  
    }
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";
}


echo"</tr>";


?>
</table>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['v']))
{
    echo"<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>ADD EVENT</a>";
    if(isset($_GET['f']))
    {
        include("eventform.php");
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is Event Form

```
<form name="eventform" name="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo $year;?>&v=true&&add=true">
<table width="400px">
<tr>
<td width="150">Title</td>
<td width="250"><input type="text" name="txttitle"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150">Detail</td>
<td width="250"><textarea name="txtdetail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' align="center"><input type="submit" name"btnadd" value="Add Event"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I guess its because you have given `isset($_GET['add']` in place of `isset($_GET['btnadd']`...

Comment: well i dont see $_GET['add'] being set anywhere.

Comment: also you need the method attribute in your form tag

Comment: I don't think you can send `$_GET` and `$_POST` at the same time. And use `!empty` instead of `isset` or use both.

Comment: You have no $_POST vars because the default `method` for form is GET, also you do not have element named `add`. Mixing GET and POST is nevre good

Comment: i even tried with ($_GET['btnadd'] and still the If statement not working

Comment: any suggestion to changing the code ? what should i add?

Comment: form method post, will not be entire solution, because of checking GET['add'], after applying method post, there should be POST['btnadd'] check

Comment: @user3314766 we do not tolerate this way of asking help. If you have too many problems in the code and the problems are pointed, you should find the solution yourself. When we tell you, you don't have method in your form tag, you should now what method is. If you don't, it shows lack of effort for solving the problem, and lack of understanding on your OWN code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['btnadd']))
{
    $title=$_GET['txttitle'];
    $detail=$_GET['txtdetail'];
    $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO book (title, detail, eventdat, dateadded) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$detail}', '{$eventdate}',now())";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlinsert, $connect);
    if($result)
    {
        echo"date has been added";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ops there was problem ";
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<form name="eventform" method="GET" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table width="400px">
<tr>
<td width="150">Title</td>
<td width="250"><input type="text" name="txttitle"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150">Detail</td>
<td width="250"><textarea name="txtdetail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' align="center"><input type="submit" name"btnadd" value="Add Event"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

method="GET" automatically adds the vars to the URL, you do not need to add them in the action.

Answer (score 0):

There are various errors in your code, but the main is that you are setting `<form name="POST">`. I believe that you want to set `<form method="POST">`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you go for method GET.. any user by just refreshing the page after sending, it would bucle your action, cause PHP will check for the url form if it has a GET method form.

also, your PHP code seems to be a bit wrong..

```
if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
    $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];
    $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO book (title, detail, eventdat, dateadded) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$detail}', '{$eventdate}',now())";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlinsert, $connect);
    if($result)
    {
        echo"date has been added";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ops there was problem ";
    }
}
```

your PHP is checking if theres a var, (array="add"), so its checking if there's an input with the name "add" in your form, i think you are trying check for "btnadd" because your submit button has that name.

and you have an error in your input:

```
<input type="submit" name"btnadd" value="Add Event">
```

you didnt enter "=", so should be:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Add Event">
```

where "btnadd" is has to be in your PHP like this

```
if(isset($_GET['btnadd']));//Exact var name
```